# Unable to use full-text search in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, storage

I want to use fulltext search in a SQL Server 2008 database but am not able to use it as the node `Storage` is not there from which I can make a new fulltext catalog. I have all the nodes present namely, Database Diagrams, Tables, Views, Synonyms, Programmability, Service Broker and Security. Just Storage is not present. I have installed the Full-text Search from the SQL Server 2008 Setup and have the SQL fulltext Filter Daemon Launcher service running in the SQL Server 2008 Configuration Manager.

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express Edition R2 Service Pack 1

Please Help!!

---

I FOUND OUT:
I found that the Storage node is not showing because i am using SSMS Express Edition. Full-Text catalogs can't be managed by the express edition. there is a free Addin available though http://fulltextmanager.codeplex.com/ but still am getting errors while creating a new catalog with this addin

Answer (score 0):

Even if you had full SSMS - you won’t be able to use full text catalogues if the SQL instance does not have it installed. Make sure the SQL server instance has the full text service running.

I.e. when you download and install sql express; make sure you download the version with Advanced Services.

Once you have confirmed the full text service is installed and running you will be able to create catalogues from SQL (no GUI in the express version of SSMS i'm afraid).

Or, to get you started, you could cheat and download the 180 day trial of SQL Server 2012 RC0 and use the fully functional SSMS to create the catalogues.

NOTE: using a Release Candidate is not best practice and you do so at your own risk

Comment: ya i have the FTS installed. Yes later i found out that SSMSE does not support GUI, so have started learning the FT DML commands. There is a free addin available in codeplex which you can use if u like http://fulltextmanager.codeplex.com/ this addin gives a GUI for handling the catalogs :) thanks for your reply